# How do you write an "array of pattern" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jsdoc

I'm trying to get `grunt-jsdoc-plugin` to work, and I'm having a small problem. In my console, I keep getting:

> ```
> Running "jsdoc:dist" (jsdoc) task
> Warning: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.
> ```

In the  `grunt-jsdoc-plugin` [documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-jsdoc-plugin), it says:

> src : an array of pattern that matches the files to extract the documentation from. You can also add the pattern to a README.md file to include it in your doc as described there.

What exactly does the phrase "array of pattern" mean? In my Gruntfile, I have simply written this, thinking that source was a relative file path:

```
  jsdoc : {
        dist : {
            src: 'testdoc2.js', 
            dest: 'doc'
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, since I'm getting that error. How am I supposed to write this exactly?
Thanks much!
~Carpetfizz

Comment: there's an example right on that very page: `src: ['src/*.js', 'test/*.js']`

Comment: array of file patterns! like `var patterns = ['*.js', '*.css'];`

Comment: Yes, but what does it do, and how do I write it if there's only one file? A link to the reference of this (patterns) would be helpful.

Comment: Looking at the source of https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc-plugin, that task doesn't appear to use `src` patterns. So I think their documentation is incorrect.

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung thanks, how do you suggest I should do it instead? Sorry, I'm a little new to Js.

Comment: Carpetfizz, Id open an issue on https://github.com/krampstudio/grunt-jsdoc-plugin/issues and ask the author of that plugin for assistance. Otherwise try looking for another plugin that does what you're looking for.

Comment: I am using that same plugin with a configuration very similar to yours, with no issues. Can you post a more complete Gruntfile.js and also what version of the plugin you are using?

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to also use an array with one item in it, like: `src: ['testdoc2.js']`